# PdfPTable.DefaultCell.Padding seems doesn't work

Tags: c#, itext, pdfptable

I am trying to define the Padding of a serie of columns that will be pushed inside my PdfPTable...

this is my code:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);
table.WidthPercentage = 100;
table.SetWidths(new float[]{25, 25, 16, 11, 11, 11});
table.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
```

There are something wrong, because when the table is generated, it does not have padding in anywhere.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this post](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/104) from the creator of iText. The `DefaultCell` only gets used when calling `AddCell` with a string, phrase, image or another table. When you manually create a cell using `New PdfPCell()` then the defaults aren't used.

**EDIT**

Here's a sample factory method:

```
private static PdfPCell CreateCell() {
    var c = new PdfPCell();
    c.Padding = 5;
    return c;
}
```

You can also skip the factory method if you're only setting properties and use object initialization:

```
var c = new PdfPCell() { Padding = 5 };
```

Comment: Well... this did help. It's not the answer, but did help to understand  a little. Thank you.

Comment: What should I do if I need to use New PdfPCell() and need Padding to my columns, since the `.Padding` attribute is private/protected set?

Comment: Most people just make a factory method that calls `New PdfPCell()` and sets up all of the correct padding and other settings.

Comment: Do you have any example about how could I do that? Thank you.

Comment: this actually did help before.